# How do I share or attend a Facebook event from out of my iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to extend my app by a feature to share a listed Facebook event on a user's wall. Also, I'd like to give the ability to mark the user as an attendee of the event.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any useful hints on this on the FB developer pages.

Comment: Share where? On Facebook? Or elsewhere?

Comment: On facebook, sorry, forgot to mention.